# How to get the contents of a number of textareas into an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a number of `textareas` like this...

```
<textarea name="a[]" id="a[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="a[]" id="a[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="a[]" id="a[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="a[]" id="a[]"></textarea>
```

Using jQuery, I would like to get value of each textarea, as an array. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `id` should be a unique identifier, often different from `name`. If you ever use any JavaScript with these `textarea`s, not having unique identifiers will cause some funky stuff to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var values = [];
$("textarea[name=a[]]").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    values.push(text);
});
```